# Perl module in @INC path, but can't be located though present. Other modules are found

Tags: perl, module, path

Perl module DBD::mysql was being found and now is not. I'm getting the error message.

`Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 
/usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /mnt/Lab/Data/IonTorrent/plugins/WH_v2_05/scripts/create_blinded_reports.pl line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /mnt/Lab/Data/IonTorrent/plugins/WH_v2_05/scripts/create_blinded_reports.pl line 13.`

I looked to see where the module was located.

```
$ perldoc -l DBD::mysql
/usr/lib64/perl5/DBD/mysql.pm
```

the path /usr/lib64/perl5 is there so why can't it find it.

Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 


use strict;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql; #<----- this is the line that error (I eliminated the header, this is actually line 13.)
use File::Slurp;
use Data::Dumper;

my ($server,$run)=@ARGV;

## variables
my $wh_report="/mnt/Lab/Data/IonTorrent/$server/$run/4_report/wh_report_".$run.".txt";
```

** Also I checked that I was on the correct server.

It also compiles fine.

```
perl -c create_blinded_reports.pl
create_blinded_reports.pl syntax OK
```

Comment: Do you really need to load `DBD::mysql`? It should be sufficient to load `DBI`.

Comment: I don't know. Let me give it a shot....currently testing

Comment: You don't/ DBI loads it when it parses the 'mysql' out of the DSN string when you call connect().

Comment: There's no problem loading it via an explicit use statement like you're doing.  The only difference between the explicit use statement vs having the DBI module load it via a require statement is the point in time when it gets loaded.  The use statement loads it during the compilation phase, and the require statement used in the DBI module loads it during the runtime phase.  If it fails during the compilation phase, then it will also fail during the runtime phase.

Comment: How did you install the module?  What are its file permissions?

Comment: Add the following before `use DBD::mysql;`: `BEGIN {
die "/usr/lib64/perl5 not in @INC\n" if !grep { $_ eq '/usr/lib64/perl5' } @INC;
stat($_) or die("stat $_: $!\n") for qw( / /usr /usr/lib64 /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/DBD /usr/lib64/perl5/DBD/mysql.pm );
open(my $fh, "<", $_) or die("open $_: $!\n") for "/usr/lib64/perl5/DBD/mysql.pm";
}`

Answer (score 1):

I dropped `use DBD::mysql;` from the code and it ran fine. Thanks!